# I'm a US citizen Can I enter US from Georgia Batumi Airport on my US passport which expires in less than 3 month?

Tags: usa, passports, us-citizens

I'm a US citizen Can I enter US from Georgia Batumi Airport  on my US passport which expires in less than 3 month?

Comment: A US citizen cannot be denied entry to the US, even if they have an expired passport or no passport, as long as they can satisfactorily prove their citizenship. The question is more whether the airline will let you board.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can enter the US as a US citizen with a valid US passport regardless of how soon is it going to expire.

> American citizens entering the U.S. must show a valid passport, U.S. passport card, Trusted Traveler Program card (NEXUS, SENTRI, Global Entry or FAST), or an enhanced driver’s license. If you have any questions, contact your carrier to find out if they require a specific document.

[usa.gov](https://www.usa.gov/enter-us)

Must Read: [U.S. Citizens - Documents needed to enter the United States and/or to travel Internationally.](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/3618/~/u.s.-citizens---documents-needed-to-enter-the-united-states-and%2For-to-travel)

Comment: The reasoning behind the rule is most countries, including the US, want to be sure your passport will still be valid when the time comes that your allowable period of stay comes to an end (and perhaps add a few months cushion). Since a US citizen has a right to stay for the rest of his/her life, this concern does not apply to citizens.